# ADF Cascading Lov Search and Select popup customization

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, lov

I have built a cascading LOV with Group and division fields **(Combo box with list of values)**. When I select a value for Group and click on `Search and Select` dialog for Division field, the SearchAndSelect popup has both Group and Division fields as search criteria(as defined in my view criteria).

Now,  is there a way to populate the **Group value** in the popup criteria, I  know the where clause uses the already entered Group value but I want to display it to the user in the SearchAndSelect popup search region.

Answer (score 1):

There is no declarative way of pre setting search field values in lov popup. Although it can be done by using a custom launchPopupListener for lov component. To know more about how to use lov popup listeners refer to [Building Custom Lovs](http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.com/2013/06/building-custom-lov-with-searchcontent.html)

Create a launchPopupListener method for your dependent lov.

`<af:inputComboboxListOfValues id="inpClv2"
    popupTitle="Search and Select: #{bindings.StateProvince.hints.label}"
    value="#{bindings.StateProvince.inputValue}"
    label="#{bindings.StateProvince.hints.label}"
    model="#{bindings.StateProvince.listOfValuesModel}"
    required="#{bindings.StateProvince.hints.mandatory}"
    columns="#{bindings.StateProvince.hints.displayWidth}"
    shortDesc="#{bindings.StateProvince.hints.tooltip}"
    partialTriggers="inpClv1"
    launchPopupListener="#{backingBeanScope.lovBean.stateLaunchPopupListener}"> 
</af:inputComboboxListOfValues>`

In launchPopupListener set the value of search criteria attribute with the value from first lov.

```
public void stateLaunchPopupListener(LaunchPopupEvent launchPopupEvent)
{
    UIXInputPopup lovComponent = (UIXInputPopup)launchPopupEvent.getSource();
    ListOfValuesModel model = lovComponent.getModel();
    if (model != null)
    {           
        QueryDescriptor queryDesc = model.getQueryDescriptor();
        /** Code to pre populate a Search and Select field**/
        ConjunctionCriterion conCrit = queryDesc.getConjunctionCriterion();
        List<Criterion> criterionList = conCrit.getCriterionList();
        for (Criterion criterion: criterionList)
        {
            AttributeDescriptor attrDesc = ((AttributeCriterion) criterion).getAttribute();
            if (attrDesc.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("CountryId")) 
            {
                List values = ((AttributeCriterion) criterion).getValues();
                values.set(0, "US"); //use the value from first lov
            }
        }
    }           
}
```